# Journal won't compile figures

Tags: includegraphics, eps, journal-publishing

I have a paper that compiles well on my PC and on Overleaf, however I need to submit it in .tex format for a journal and upload the figures separately in .eps format.

So I upload all the files (the tex and figures in .eps) via the journal system, but when I select "build PDF for approval", the outcome file displays just a bunch of pdftex compiler stuff that I paste below (the same text appears for all figures)... From what I understand it is not finding the figures... But I uploaded all of them via the journal system... What gives?

```
LaTeX Warning: File `fig1a_sem_hyb.eps' not found on input line 535.
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <fig1a_sem_hyb.eps>
(epstopdf) Output file: <fig1a_sem_hyb-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf) Command: <repstopdf --outfile=fig1a_sem_hyb-epsconverte
d-to.pdf fig1a_sem_hyb.eps>
(epstopdf) \includegraphics on input line 535.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `fig1a_sem_hyb-eps-converted-to.pdf' not
found
: using draft setting.
See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.535 \end{tabular}}
Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
```

Comment: Please edit your posting to show some inputs, such as the passage around where you specify the `fig1a_sem_hyb.eps` file name. Please also state which document class you employ. Finally, what happens if you leave off the file name extension `.eps` in all cases?

Comment: Are you sure there is no copy-and-paste error? The `epstopdf` command seems to specify an `outputfile` that is missing a hyphen (between `eps` and `converted`). Is it possible for you to upload also PDF versions of your graphics, in addition to the eps file, and see if the journal system will build then?

Comment: Questions like this however are probably best directed to the Journal, especially if it is due to something being broken on their installation.

Comment: Because the log, is clear that the journal  really the figures in the pdf format. May be instructions are outdated and the submission of images is not really restricted to the eps format,  so you can just rename  your local  `<whatever>-eps-convert-to.pdf` to `<whatever>.pdf` and submit only these files, but changing also the argument of \includegraphic to  `<whatever>.pdf` or just `<whatever>` without any extension. Otherwise,  better ask to the journal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried changing the figures to pdf or to png and altering the .tex accordingly. Still nada. Funny thing is that it compiles normally either way in my computer. I ended up sending an email to the journal